# Seguir ruta trazada en la api de google maps en android

Tags: android

Estoy diseñando una aplicación en android studio con la API de Google Maps, la situación es que el código que he realizado ya me traza la ruta de punto a punto pero no logro ir borrando el camino ya realizado cuando sigo la ruta marcada!

Comment: **[edit] tu pregunta** agregando el código que uses - no necesariamente todo el proyecto, solamente el fragmento de código que uses - para lograr lo que describes en tu pregunta y añade el (o los) posible(s) error(es) que tengas.

Comment: (Nunca he utilizado GM para estos propósitos) pero como idea : "Podrías generar una lista vacía donde almacenes la nueva traza. Calcular el punto más cercano a la traza original. Recorrer las coordenadas de la traza original, obteniendo "trozos de la traza" teniendo en cuenta el punto(i) y el punto-(i + 1) dentro del bucle, si el punto (más cercano a la traza) intersecta con este trozo de la traza, empieza a coger las coordenadas para la nueva traza desde el punto más cercano y el punto(i + 1) en adelante.

Comment: @Override public void onDirectionFinderSuccess(List<Route> routes) { progressDialog.dismiss(); polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>(); originMarkers = new ArrayList<>(); destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>(); for (Route route : routes) { try { mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(route.startLocation, 5)); Log.e("DURATION", route.duration.text); Log.e("DISTANCE",route.distance.text); ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDuration)).setText(route.duration.text); ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDistance)).setText(route.distance.text); originMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions() //.ico

Comment: Ese metodo lo utilizo para marcar la ruta de un punto a otro! pero la ruta se queda estatica cuando empiezo a moverme yo, y lo que quiero es que la ruta se vaya moviendo mediante me voy moviendo yo! me explico?